# What does if(ctr%2) mean?

Tags: c

I want to know know what this code does. All I know is that the loop (adding 1) will stop when `ctr==20` but what does `if(ctr%2)` mean here?

```
    sum=0;
    for(ctr=0; ctr< 20; ctr++)
    {
    if (ctr % 2)
        continue;
    sum += 1;
    }
    printf (“%d\n”,sum);
```

Comment: `%` is [Modulo Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: it is testing if `ctr` is an odd

Answer (score 3):

It tests if `ctr` is an odd number.  `ctr % 2` will evaluate to 0 (false) if `ctr` is even and 1 if it is odd.  Anything non-zero is considered true in the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

It effectively means *skip odd numbers*.  The condition `ctr % 2` says that the reminder by the division of *ctr* and number 2 should be different than 0, but there is only one possible value that meets such criteria and it is number 1. So the condition can be written also as `ctr % 2 == 1`.